# How can i make 'text' to 'downloadable url'?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I make chrome extension, which download some files from website.
i want write some log with txt file, because my program has some error and i want save error to txt file.

but i can't find how to do it.

someone say it's impossible.
i try to search, some questions say just 'app' can do it, but extension can't.
if i want this functions, i must change my program to web app? but i don't know anything about that...

'download file' is possible, download is write file to filesystem.
i think, 'write text file' is so easy work then download image and sound files....

why not??? what's diffrent??

i see many questions, blog and document, but i cant know clearly.

*to sum up

I want make some text to downloadable file. If i can get downloadable file and it's url, everything is perfect.

i see this extension, i think i can do it. but i don't know how to do it.
please teach me how do it!

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-text-to-file/mkepenkbhepjelljcfiooignmpfgochi/related

Comment: This question is asked regularly and the answer is still the same. If you don't want to use an additional external utility, extensions can only download to the default downloads directory using chrome.downloads API just like the extension you've linked does so simply inspect its source code and see the documentation.

Comment: @ wOxxOm I already read document of chrome.downloads. but i cant understand how to download my text! i think download api is key, but "how to make text to downloadable url" is not written. that's my questions.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I understand from your question that you want to write some text into .txt file and it should be automatically downloaded for your users. For that, here I am writing code in JavaScript which will surely helps you.

```
var fileText = "Your content which you want to save in file";

var fileBlob = new Blob([fileText], {
    type: 'text/plain'
});
var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(fileBlob);
var fileName = 'mytextfile.txt';

var fileOptions = {
    filename: fileName,
    url: fileUrl,
    conflictAction: 'uniquify'
};
fileOptions.saveAs = true;
```

It will automatically download mytextfile.txt file with your given contents. You can implement this logic in your chrome extension as per your way.

Comment: i'll try it. thanks!
if i success,i select your answer.

Comment: Thank you @Redwings